# Нужны ли запятые в уточняющем обороте?

Tags: пунктуация

И вот (,) при работе над материалами к этим главам (,) мы были удивлены весьма и весьма сильно.

Answer (score 1):

Обособление оборота факультативно и зависит от контекста.

Если первым планом представлена тема восприятия, то уточняющий оборот обособляется.

Если же оборот является предметом, о котором сообщается, то обособлять его не следует.